# Erro - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Tags: php

Esta aparecendo um erro de sintaxe na linha 13, poderiam me ajudar a decifrar, não estou encontrando.

OBS: em *localhost* ele funciona, mas no *server* web apresenta o erro.

```
<!--Início Scritp PHP-->
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'conexao.php';
    $nome     = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $empresa  = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'empresa', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $telefone = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'telefone', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $email    = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $endereco = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'endereco', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $cnpj     = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'cnpj', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $obs      = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'obs', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $querySelect = $link->query("select email from tb_clientes");
    $array_emails = []; **<- esta linha**
    while($emails = $querySelect->fetch_assoc()):
        $emails_existentes = $emails['email'];
        array_push($array_emails,$emails_existentes);
    endwhile;
    if(in_array($email,$array_emails)):
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='center red-text'>".'Já existe um cliente cadastrado com esse E-mail!'."</p>";
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
        else:
        $queryInsert = $link->query("insert into tb_clientes values (default,'$nome','$empresa','$telefone','$email','$endereco','$cnpj','$obs')");
        $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
        if($affected_rows > 0):
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='center green-text'>".'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'."</p>";
            header("Location: cadastro.php");
        endif;
    endif;
?>
<!--Fim Scritp PHP-->
```

Comment: A notação de *array* com colchetes, `[]`, só foi adicionada na versão 5.4. Qual é a versão do PHP do seu servidor?

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela rápida resposta, ela estava em 5.2, mudei para a 5.6 para teste e apareceu mais três erros, testei na 7.0 e também deu os três erros.

Comment: Se for numa hospedagem, principalmente paga, saia correndo. Não existe justificativa nenhuma pra ter um PHP tão obsoleto, a desculpa de "compatibilidade com o que tá rodando" (no caso de hospedagem "profissional") na verdade se traduz pra "não tenho competência para trabalhar com administração de servidor". Me assusta saber que tem lugar fácil pra baixar essas versões.

Comment: @Bacco - Sim é hospedagem paga, ela vem como padrão na 5.2, e sim não tenho competência para trabalhar porque é a primeira vez que estou fazendo isso, mesmo pesquisando, até porque seu tivesse competência não estaria perguntando e pedindo ajuda.

Comment: @RodrigoBernardoVieira nao disse sobre sua competência, disse o pessoal da hospedagem, que deveria ter obrigação de zelar pela atualização do sistema (a não ser que voluntariamente você solicitasse um sistema legado sabendo que tem problemas de segurança). Seu papel é desenvolver, e vc paga eles para manterem algo em ordem para você, então entendo que a prestação de serviço está deixando a desejar.

Comment: @Bacco - Opa então lhe peço desculpas interpretei muito mal seu comentário, achei que fosse direcionado para mim, mil desculpas novamente.

Comment: @RodrigoBernardoVieira nao precisa pedir desculpas, eu é que fico preocupado de ter soado ofensivo sem a intenção.

Comment: Até porque, foi um desabafo pq eu vejo muito isso acontecendo, e olha que tem alguns nomes "famosos" no mercado que fazem essa loucura. De qq forma, como você já leu a recomendação, vou apagar meus comentários em alguns minutos para nao deixar bagunça aqui no seu post.

Comment: @Bacco Sem problemas, obrigado estamos junto...

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o que entendi, tu está tentando criar um array vazio.

O [] foi adicionado a partir do php 5.4. De uma olhada nesta documentação.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Outra alternativa é criar esse array vazio dessa forma.

$array = array();

Comment: Acho que a alternativa viável seria atualizar o PHP mesmo xD

Comment: eu obtive um erro parecido com esse e acabei fazendo isso para solucionar esse problema. Estou usando laravel.

Comment: Se for uma limitação da aplicação ter, obrigatoriamente, que usar uma versão ultrapassada, sim, seria uma solução. Se não for, não há justificativa para não atualizar a linguagem e usufruir de todas as melhorias.

Comment: Sim, está certo. Concordo que a melhor alternativa seja ele atualizar seu PHP.

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pelas respostas, ela estava em 5.2, mudei para a 5.6 para teste e apareceu mais três erros, testei na 7.0 e também deu os três erros.

Comment: Quais seriam esses erros?

Comment: 1º erro Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home2/rcbwde18/public_html/sistema_rcbwdesign/cliente/create.php:2) in /home2/rcbwde18/public_html/sistema_rcbwdesign/cliente/create.php on line 3

Comment: 2º erro Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/rcbwde18/public_html/sistema_rcbwdesign/cliente/create.php:2) in /home2/rcbwde18/public_html/sistema_rcbwdesign/cliente/conexao.php on line 2

Comment: conexao.php
<?php
    $utf8 = header("Content-Tyoe:text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $link=new mysqli('localhost','rcbwde18_rcbwd19','AU[3,YGE!^yn','rcbwde18_db_cadastro_01');
    $link->set_charset('utf8');
?>

Comment: 3º erro Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/rcbwde18/public_html/sistema_rcbwdesign/cliente/create.php:2) in /home2/rcbwde18/public_html/sistema_rcbwdesign/cliente/create.php on line 20

Comment: Esses erros são pq vc esta mandando coisas como isso aqui pro HTML antes do PHP `<!--Início Scritp PHP-->` Se pesquisar a mensagem de erro aqui mesmo, vai achar uma boa explicação do que ocorre: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+modify+header+information

Comment: @Bacco - cara valeu, tirei <!--Início Scritp PHP-->, e funcionou perfect!!!, obrigado.